# Executing javascript from a CORS request

Tags: javascript, html, cors

I have an scenario where I would like to create a reusable graphing widget using HTML/Javascript/CSS.  Let's say the actual graph is implemented with something like Flot.  I have another application in a different domain where I would like to reuse the graph component.  Looking thru my options it seems the best way to pull in this content would be thru a CORS request.  What I'm unsure of is the following:

1) How to invoke the javascript required to render the flot chart (ie. callign the plot function on the flot object).

2) Does the CSS that drives the graph look have to be imported in the header section or can it be directly defined in the  tag?

```
<html><body><other content from users site>
<!--this content is pulled in from CORS REquest-->
<div>
   Can I import other javascript here simply using <script src="other domain">?
   <flot component with javascript required to drive the chart>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly by the spec, `<style>` is only allowed in the head, browsers will tolerate it elsewhere.

Can I import other JavaScript here simply using `<script src="other domain">`?
Yes you can, just make sure it's a script you can trust ;)

Comment: How would I invoke an 'initialize' method or something that needs to be called in the script that is imported?